# Capturing changes occurring on tables?

Tags: postgresql, odoo

I want to see what tables and fields in PostgreSQL that a module in OpenERP is changing/updating when it runs.

Any suggestions?

```
 application_name           | pgAdmin III - Query Tool   | client
 bytea_output               | escape                     | session
 client_encoding            | UNICODE                    | session
 client_min_messages        | notice                     | session
 DateStyle                  | ISO,MDY                    | session
 default_text_search_config | pg_catalog.english         | configuration file
 lc_messages                | English_United States.1252 | configuration file
 lc_monetary                | English_United States.1252 | configuration file
 lc_numeric                 | English_United States.1252 | configuration file
 lc_time                    | English_United States.1252 | configuration file
 listen_addresses           | *                          | configuration file
 log_destination            | csvlog                     | configuration file
 log_line_prefix            | %t                         | configuration file
 log_timezone               | US/Pacific                 | configuration file
 logging_collector          | on                         | configuration file
 max_connections            | 100                        | configuration file
 max_stack_depth            | 2MB                        | environment variable
 port                       | 5432                       | configuration file
 shared_buffers             | 32MB                       | configuration file
 TimeZone                   | US/Pacific                 | configuration file
```

Answer (score 1):

If OpenERP is using a specific ROLE when it connects ("openerp" is used in the example), you can log the statements a couple of different ways:

1). `ALTER ROLE openerp SET log_min_duration_statement TO 0;`

2). `ALTER ROLE openerp SET log_statement TO 'mod';`

My preference is option #1, but you might want to try both.

To revert the settings to defaults:

1). `ALTER ROLE openerp SET log_min_duration_statement TO DEFAULT;`

2). `ALTER ROLE openerp SET log_statement TO DEFAULT;` -- or `'none'`

To see what the current settings are (when not set via ROLE), paste the results of the following query:

```
SELECT  name, 
        current_setting(name) AS current_setting, 
        source
FROM pg_settings
WHERE source <> ALL (ARRAY['default'::text, 'override'::text]);
```

Comment: Thanks.  I tried both those, and I also changed the values in the conf file. It's now writing a csv but there's nothing in it.

Comment: Did you restart the OpenERP connection to the db? I've seen the same thing -- lack of log output -- from JDBC, and the solution is to restart the JDBC connections (or connection pooler).

Comment: @JimB Another thing: are you connecting to the db as the specific role that you issued the ALTER TABLE for? I assume so, but it's worth checking.

Comment: since i modified the conf file, i shouldn't need to alter roles, correct? and i have stopped/started the server, did a complete reboot of the machine and still nothing... i know i'm probably missing something minor.  i'll edit my original post and put the conf file in there.

Comment: ok, not putting the conf file here, what a pain...  i can email it to anyone who thinks they can help tho.

Comment: I suspect that the data is logging to a location that you are not expecting. What db version and OS are you using. Where did you check for log output?

Comment: postgresql 9.2, Windows 7, and the log file is going to the default location - and since i set the conf file to create a csv, it is actually creating the csv file, there's just nothing in it...  conf file line:  log_directory = 'pg_log'

Comment: here's the data from the query - added to my original post

Comment: Well, if you've restarted your server (for `logging_collector` to take effect), then it should be working. If you issue some invalid query, eg "selllect 1", does it emit anything to the .csv log file that you are looking in?

Comment: Can you also paste the output of `select * from pg_roles` and point out the role that your app is connecting as?

Comment: just one role:   "openpg";t;t;t;t;t;t;t;-1;"********";"";"";10

Comment: Did you try the `alter role openpg set log_min_duration_statement to 0;` command?

Comment: i did run the alter role and it returned success.  but i thought since i changed that in the conf file i wouldn't have to run that?  it's still only logging errors...  i'm about to give up...

Comment: Yeah, if it is set globally in the postgresql.conf then you shouldn't need to set it per role. There is something being overlooked here and I can't think of what else to check. If you've reloaded (and/or restarted) your cluster, restarted your OpenERP connections, and you are seeing results (from a deliberately bad query), then I don't know what else to suggest. If it wasn't Windows I'd suggest looking at the running postmaster process and see what flags/options it is running with.